# Increment the order number by 1 in a controller when a new item is uploaded using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am wanting to increment the order number by 1 when a new item is uploaded. I have an image uploader that uploads multiple images, basically I want the order to increment if a new image is uploaded but keep the existing images order number the same. I tried using the `increment()` method but when I tried this it incremented the existing images order number which I don't want, but then the new image order number produced a strange number of 25 for example. I'm a bit unsure why this is happening or am I missing something important, thank you.

This code is set in the store function in the controller.

```php
if($request->hasfile('images'))
{
    foreach($request->file('images') as $image)
    {
        $filenameWithExt = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

        $path = $image->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);

        $image = new Images;
        $increment = Images::increment('order', 1);
        $image->order = $increment;
        $image->images = $fileNameToStore;
        $image->post_id = $post->id;
        $image->save();
    }
} else {
    $fileNameToStore = null;
}
```

Comment: Change `$image->order = $increment;` to `$image->increment('order');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a max() to get the latest increment value:

```
$max = Images::where('post_id', $post->id)->max('order');
$order = $max+1;
```

Comment: Thanks that's working now for the delete would it be the opposite? So if there were 3 images and image order number 2 was deleted, would it change order number 3 to order number 2

Comment: This should be a different question, but you should delete from your Images model and then $images = Images::where('post_id', $post->id)->get();    and then on a foreach loop update your order based on the $key value.